# Cache Management options disappeared after installing turpentine

Tags: magento-1.9, varnish, turpentine

Trying to setup **Varnish 3.0.5** with **Magento 1.9.2.4** -

Installed turpentine with modaman
[image: output of installation through modman]
So, i think i've successfully installed turpentine

But after that when i'm going to cache management no option is visible

[image]

what's wrong with installation proccess ?

Comment: Can you please check after removing var/cache and var/session directory?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have this extension active

```
https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/issues/1079
```

In the Admin set
System > Configuration > ADVANCED > Advanced > Disable Modules Output > Nexcess Turpentine
to Enable